# Run two instance of the same app - split view

Tags: instance, ios9, uisplitview, ios-multithreading

Didn’t have my hand on the iPad air or the iPad Pro. Would it be possible to run two instance of the same app in the two split views?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.
The only way to do that would be to have 2 seperate app identifiers for the same actual application (set at the developer level).